# Add values of same Key in array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

Trying to add values of same key but with iterating it. here is my array

```
arr = [ {a: 10, b: 5, c: 2}, {a: 5, c: 3}, { b: 15, c: 4}, {a: 2}, {} ]
```

Want to converted it like

```
{a: 17, b: 20, c: 9}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do this by making use of [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`Hash#merge`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
arr.reduce {|acc, h| acc.merge(h) {|_,v1,v2| v1 + v2 }}
#=> {:a=>17, :b=>20, :c=>9}
```

Comment: `(Hash.new {|h, k| 0})` can be omitted, but `merge!` should be replaced with `merge` (otherwise, `arr[0]` will be modified)

Comment: @falsetru Thanks for the tip - will update the answer

Comment: You can remove `({})` if you replace `merge!` with `merge`

Comment: @Stefan  Thanks for that nice tip.

Comment: I think that is what @falsetru tried to suggest earlier. Note the parentheses in the comment ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`each_with_object` to the rescue:

```
result = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, result|
  hash.each { |key, value| result[key] += value}
end

p result
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer each_with_object over reduce/inject (because it has a more logical order of the block parameters) and i think it is more readable than using merge. That being said: the merge solution is pretty sleek.

Answer (score 4):

**#1 Use a "counting hash"**

Edit: I just noticed that @Pascal posted the same solution earlier. I'll leave mine for the explanation.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h,g| h.each { |k,v| g[k] += v } }
  #=> {:a=>17, :b=>20, :c=>9}
```

`h = Hash.new(0)` is a counting hash with a default value of zero. That means that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns zero (but the hash is not altered). Ruby expands `h[k] += 4` to `h[k] = h[k] + 4`, so if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right side of the equality equals zero.

**#2 Use [Hash#update](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-update)**

Specifically, use the form of this method (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g.update(h) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {:a=>17, :b=>20, :c=>9}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan : P

Comment: @CarySwoveland you don't need a default value in #2, the inner block is only executed if the key exists in both hashes.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. It's late and I'm bushed from building stairs all day, so the little grey cells seem to have nodded off.