# compute hash value of same key ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I start with a basic hash where the key is a string and value an integer.

```
hash = {"a"=>2, "b"=>3}
```

Then what I try to achieve is that i want to push several times into that hash a new hash with different keys or / and same :

```
hash2 = {"c"=>4, "a"=>5}
```

The result should be

```
h_result = {"a"=>7, "b"=>3, "c"=>4}
```

The first thing would be to push the new hash and keep the duplicate keys.
I saw that answer = [How can I merge two hashes without overwritten duplicate keys in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980794/how-can-i-merge-two-hashes-without-overwritten-duplicate-keys-in-ruby) but it seems that it's not working..

Then I think I should match the same keys and compute the values. But again I can't find the answer.

Thanks guys

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific issue is--the simplest thing to do is to iterate over the incoming hash's key/value pairs, if the key is found in the original hash, set the new value to existing + incoming, if it isn't, add the incoming key/value pair. Can you be more clear about what the problem is?

Comment: this question has been asked a time or two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091487/sum-2-hashes-attributes-with-the-same-key, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453511/group-hashes-by-keys-and-sum-the-values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868886/merge-and-sum-hashes-inside-a-ruby-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004998/add-values-of-same-key-in-array-of-hashes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003362/array-with-hash-how-to-merge-same-keys-and-add-its-value

Comment: Hello @DaveNewton what i want to do is the simplest thing you're talking about, i just don't know how to code it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum 2 hashes attributes with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091487/sum-2-hashes-attributes-with-the-same-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compute equal keys in the hash what you are looking for is the `merge` method in the Hash class.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge

> Returns a new hash containing the contents of other_hash and the
>   contents of hsh. If no block is specified, the value for entries with
>   duplicate keys will be that of other_hash. Otherwise the value for
>   each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key,
>   its value in hsh and its value in other_hash.

When you pass a block to the `merge` method it will yield both old value and new value, and the you can do your computation there.

For instance:

```
hash  = {"a"=>2, "b"=>3}
hash2 = {"c"=>4, "a"=>5}

result = hash.merge(hash2) { |key, old_val, new_val| old_val + new_val }

p result #=> {"a"=>7, "b"=>3, "c"=>4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block and tell Ruby what to do when the key exists in both hashes – in this example just add the value from the second hash to the value from the first hash.

```
hash.merge(hash2) { |key, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
#=> { "a" => 7, "b" => 3, "c" => 4 }
```